# Detecting whether a user is behind a proxy

Tags: php, http, proxy

I'm trying to figure out how I could detect whether people logging into my site are behind a proxy or not.  I've read that you can detect a person's real IP address through embeddable objects (Flash and Java).  However, I haven't been able to actually find any examples or source for this.

I'm using PHP and I've read that looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`, etc. would detect most proxies but so far I haven't been able to by testing with TOR (maybe TOR doesn't flag those, but I've read that anonymous proxies still show `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`).  I'd like to try doing it with a java servlet, if possible.  Could anyone point me in the right direction (preferably with examples?)  I saw some code on ha.ckers.org but they only showed the client side and not the server side.

Comment: If I could ask: why do you want to detect proxy users? Outside of some possible differences in their connection usage (a network footprint, if you will), it really won't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TOR does not supply any server headers such as X_FORWARDED_FOR, so your best bet is to use a list of all known exit nodes. A list can be found at https://torstat.xenobite.eu/.

For other proxies, you can look at server headers. Possible server headers of interest include:

```
HTTP_VIA 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED
HTTP_FORWARDED 
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP 
VIA
X_FORWARDED_FOR 
FORWARDED_FOR
X_FORWARDED FORWARDED
CLIENT_IP
FORWARDED_FOR_IP
HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION
```

In PHP, you can get the value of these fields in the `$_SERVER[] superglobal`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for that list and other info.

Comment: In case you want to check a client IP against a fresh and up-to-date (and you don't want to manage that by yourself) list of Tor nodes, public proxies, bad bots, and spammers, I suggest having a look at my service: Ipregistry (https://ipregistry.co).

Answer (score 4):

If your want to check weather the user is using proxy or not you can go with the port scan and checking the headers when request is made. These method will reveal public IP if the proxy is non-transparent (By the way there are two types of IP address public and private IP address). But this will not work if it is transparent proxy.

```
function detectProxy() {
  $sockport = false;

     $proxyports=array(80,8080,6588,8000,3128,3127,3124,1080,553,554);
 for ($i = 0; $i <= count($proxyports); $i++) {
 if(@fsockopen($ipaddress,$proxyports[$i],$errstr,$errno,0.5)){
 $sockport=true;
 }
 }

 if(
     isset($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP'])
     || isset($_SERVER['VIA'])
     || isset($_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
     || isset($_SERVER['FORWARDED_FOR'])
     || isset($_SERVER['X_FORWARDED'])
     || isset($_SERVER['FORWARDED'])
     || isset($_SERVER['CLIENT_IP'])
     || isset($_SERVER['FORWARDED_FOR_IP'])
     || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION'])
     || $sockport === true
 ) {
     echo 'User is using proxy';
 }
 else{
     echo ''user is not using proxy';
  }
 }
```

Second method is by using DNS server by allocating sub domain to each user.

You can also check this site [proxy checker](https://www.sabiduria.in/tracker/Do-you-think-you-know-more-about-your-device-than-we-know/) which will show public and private IP address even when you are using proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Neither Java Applets or Flash is supposed to leak the client IP. I know that older versions of Flash had a security flaw that made it possible. Most probably that is patched by now.

I've never used TOR but from what I read it seems to be implemented as a kind of VPN and thus the browser will not be aware of it at all.

Why do you need to know if the user is behind a proxy?

Comment: Oh, I had noticed the issue with Flash was changed after Flash 9.0 so you're right.  I'm wanting to keep people from using proxies on a game that I've made so when I ban spammers they can't create new accounts with a proxy.  I know it wouldn't be fool proof, but I'd like to just make it a little more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option you can try using https. The user IP then should be visible to you. However don't know about office users behind SSL proxies.

Answer (score 1):

By looking for the following header fields you should some proxys.

```
VIA
FORWARDED
USERAGENT_VIA
X_FORWARDED_FOR
PROXY_CONNECTION
XPROXY_CONNECTION
HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
```

As for blocking TOR you are best of blocking the TOR exit nodes with iptables.

And if you really must be sure you could try some "semi-malicious" things like embedding some flash or java in your page which sends you back the real client ip. But that has only limited scope as you might just get the local ip if he is in e.g. a LAN you get something like 192.168.1.x

Comment: I've heard about those headers, but trying to access them from the $_SERVER superglobal in PHP doesn't seem to help.  I've yet to see those indexes in the $_SERVER superglobal, but I've only used TOR so maybe that's different.  As far as I know, TOR is an anonymous proxy and still should flag X_FORWARDED_FOR but nothing showed up in testing.

Comment: Oh great. The exact same answer with my headers replicated with a HTTP_ prepended gets accepted an mine gets a down vote??

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the client IP address, the simplest is to pass it to a service that maintains an up-to-date list of TOR exit nodes. You can for instance use [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service):

https://api.ipregistry.co/89.187.143.81?key=tryout

where `89.187.143.81` must be replaced by your client IP and `tryout` by your API key.

In the output, look at the field `security -> is_tor_exit`. If the boolean is true, then your client is using Tor.