# How Detect Anonymous, Misleading Proxy Request Using PHP Code?

Tags: php, http, proxy

I want check whether an incoming HTTP request is coming from a Transparent proxy, Misleading proxy, SOCKS Proxy using PHP code.I had developed one application in PHP.

I had checked the client using proxy or not from `$_SERVER` Request.I helped blow link for this

[Detecting whether a user is behind aproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000924/detecting-whether-a-user-is-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting whether a user is behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000924/detecting-whether-a-user-is-behind-a-proxy) - Also useful: [Transparent Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxies)

Comment: [hakre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre),I know " Detecting whether a user is behind a proxy" and Transparent proy.This is not useful for me.So its not duplicate.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, there is no way to distinguish a truly *transparent* proxy, so there is no way to block them. You could, in theory, try to identify the TCP/IP stack of the remote system and try to match that to the OS declared in the user-agent. However, this approach is erorr-prone, impractical, extremely complicated, and naturally cannot distinguish a "real" webbrowser from a proxy if both run on the same OS.

If you define a misleading proxy as one that alters the content, you can check the content with JavaScript. For example, if the proxy adds `<img src="http://evil.com/ad">` to all requests, check `document.querySelector('img[src="http://evil.com/ad"]').length > 0`.

Comment: Yes,You are correct, i am trouble with this.Some proxy changing the IP address in each request.is there any way to find out this?

Comment: @AbdulMajeed: Trace the IP across requests, e.g. with a `$_SESSION`. Then you can detect changes.

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Naturally, a request routed through a proxy will come from the proxy's IP address, and not the webbrowser's. Instead of worrying about the existence of a proxy, why don't you worry about the  problem the proxy introduces? *Why* do you want to detect whether a user is behind a proxy?

Comment: @phihag:I have created on application.

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Sorry, I don't understand. It looks like your comment may be missing one or more sentences.

Comment: @phihag:I have created one web application in php.I want to give some amount for each click(Just like google adsence).So i want to check whether the click is relevant or not.I already checked user agent, remote IP address(allow One click per IP).If some user using Proxy the system will be make issues(We need to give amount for each click because each request coming from deferent IP).I hope this will help full to you.

Comment: @AbdulMajeed It looks like your problem is completely unrelated to the presence of a proxy. Different users may share a computer, and share an IP address whenever NAT is used. You should set a cookie or use [more advanced user/browser identification](http://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf).

Comment: @phihag: Thanks for giving information.I will try cookie or Browser Identification.