# Getting IP address in JSP

Tags: jsp, ip

I used the following code to get the visitors IPaddress.

```
<div id="news1"><%=request.getRemoteAddr()%></div>
```

When I run the code, I get the following output

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Can I know what is actually happening in this line? I am not using any proxy and got this output when connecting from local host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This address is the [Loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) address (the IP of your computer, seen from your computer) expressed in IPv6 (usually  `127.0.0.1` in IPv4, aliased with host name `localhost`)

Comment: Thank you. In case, if I am connecting through other system, Is there any way to check if visitor is using proxy or not?

Comment: You could guess if it is by checking for some HTTP header fields, such as [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), or checking with a list of web proxies. This might be an unreliable practice. It's an interesting enough topic to be a good independent question, like this one [Detecting whether a user is behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000924/851811). There are good answers there.