# Why is my original IP still visible even when I use CURLOPT_PROXY with Curl?

Tags: php, http, curl, proxy

I'm using curl against a target site that has a quota of page views per IP, e.g. 5000 page views per IP per day. Now I'm trying to get more by switching IP addresses.

I'm using some proxy IP addresses for $10 / month. So I added them to PHP curl via the CURLOPT_PROXY option, but somehow the target site is still able to detect my original IP and doesn't give new quotas for the proxy IPs.

I tried to curl some other sites with the proxy on and it's working properly.

Why is it that the target site is able to detect my original IP even when I use a proxy with curl in PHP? How to make my original IP completely hidden in this sense?

This seems also the case when I'm browsing sites through proxy but somehow they are still able to detect my local computer IP address.

Why is it like this? Is there something inherently impossible to hide IP via HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of proxies:

- **Transparent**: your real ip is added to the http header.
- **Distorting**: your real ip is hidden or a fake one is added to the http header. But the proxy "identy" is added in the header so that the client knows that you are going through a proxy.
- **(Highly) Anonymous**: your ip is hidden and the proxy "identy" is hidden. The client believes that it is a "direct" connection.

So you are certainly using a Transparent proxy.

To test that, you could simply:

1) Create this "dummy" page on your site:

```
<?php
mail('your@email.com', 'Proxy', print_r($_SERVER, true));
```

2) "Curl it"

3) Check the [http header values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001629/125075) received in the email.

Answer (score 0):

The Proxy probably sets the http-header [X-Forwarded-For](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) and the target site is aware of that.

This has to be disabled in the proxy.