# How to hide my real IP address?

Tags: curl, proxy, web-scraping, ip, spoofing

I want to read data from a website but blacked my real IP address
I want to use IP list to read data :

[proxy list 1](http://www.freeproxylists.net/)
[proxy list 2](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/)

I am test [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869472/why-is-my-original-ip-still-visible-even-when-i-use-curlopt-proxy-with-curl) to hide my real IP address and my IP address not exists in header but target website find my real IP adrress and block it

I am using php with curl
And my target website written by python

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code to visit your target site:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8080';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```